# Stop the loop after the n-th element - puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

How can I stop the loop after the fifth link?

This is my code

```
  await page.goto('https://old.reddit.com',{"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
  const a_elems = await page.$$('.thumbnail');

  for (var i=0; i<a_elems.length; i++) {                  
     const elem = a_elems[i];
     const href = await page.evaluate(e => e.href, elem); 
     const newPage = await browser.newPage();
     await newPage.goto(href,{"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
   }
```

I tried `nth-child` but it doesn't work.
Do you have any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by simply add the condition in your for loop

```
 for (var i=0; i<a_elems.length && i<5; i++) {                  
 const elem = a_elems[i];
 const href = await page.evaluate(e => e.href, elem); 
 const newPage = await browser.newPage();
 await newPage.goto(href,{"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
```

}

Comment: Thats clean +1, but might be easy to overlook when observing the code. I would make it an if statement at the end in the for loop `if (i === 4) break;`

Comment: Indeed, it is so simple. I think I'm too tired, I need a break. Thanks a lot!